If I roll $k$ $n$-sided dice, what's the probability that no combination of them sums to a multiple of $n$?
Suppose that $(X_i)_{i\in\{1,\dots,k\}}$ is i.i.d. uniform on $\mathbb Z / n\mathbb{Z}$. I am interested in computing $$
F_{k}(n)= P\left(\sum_{j\in S} X_j \not\equiv 0 \mod n\hspace{3pt}\forall\hspace{3pt}S\text{ a nonempty subset of }\{1,\dots,k\}\right)
$$
(One can think of this as a dice problem, as stated in the title: If you roll $k$ $n$-sided dice, what is the probability that no combination of dice sums to a multiple of $n$? This question arose in the context of game design, though for the game concept I'm working with I would only need an answer for some particular values of $n$ and $k$ that can be computed by simple enumeration, it would be neat to have a general result, especially since I've got enough different $n$'s and $k$'s to consider that brute forcing it would be tedious.)
Obvious stuff
Trivially, $F_k(n)$ is decreasing in $k$.
We also have that $F_k(n)$ is supermultiplicative as a function of $n$, i.e. if $n,m$ are relatively prime, then $$
F_k(nm)\ge F_k(n)F_k(m)
$$
Note that $\mathbb Z / (nm)\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb Z / n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb Z / m\mathbb{Z}$ and hence we can write $X_i = (Y_i,Z_i)$ for $Y_i\sim\mathrm{Unif}(\mathbb Z / n\mathbb{Z})$ and $Z_i \sim \mathrm{Unif}(\mathbb Z / m\mathbb{Z})$, such that $Y_i$ and $Z_i$ are independent and each i.i.d. Then \begin{eqnarray}
F_k(nm)&=& P\left(\sum_{j\in S} X_j \not\equiv 0 \mod (nm)\hspace{3pt}\forall\hspace{3pt}S\text{ a nonempty subset of }\{1,\dots,k\}\right)\\
&=& P\left(\sum_{j\in S} Y_j \not\equiv 0 \mod n\text{ and }\sum_{j\in S} Z_j \not\equiv 0 \mod n\hspace{3pt}\forall\hspace{3pt}S\text{ a nonempty subset of }\{1,\dots,k\}\right)\\
&\ge& P\left(\sum_{j\in S} Y_j \not\equiv 0 \mod n\text{ and }\sum_{j\in T} Z_j \not\equiv 0 \mod m\hspace{3pt}\forall\hspace{3pt}S,T\text{ nonempty subsets of }\{1,\dots,k\}\right)\\
&=& P\left(\sum_{j\in S} Y_j \not\equiv 0 \mod n\hspace{3pt}\forall\hspace{3pt}S\text{ a nonempty subset of }\{1,\dots,k\}\right)P\left(\sum_{j\in T} Z_j \not\equiv 0 \mod m\hspace{3pt}\forall\hspace{3pt}T\text{ a nonempty subset of }\{1,\dots,k\}\right)= F_k(n)F_k(m)
\end{eqnarray}
We also ought to have $F_k(n)=0$ for $k\ge n$ and $F_k(n)>0$ for $k<n$: To show this, it suffices to show $F_n(n)=0$ and $F_{n-1}(n)>0$. $F_n(n)= 0$ may be proven by contradiction. Suppose that there exists $(x_1,\dots,x_k)\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb Z)^k$ such that any sum of components of $\vec x$ is nonzero. Let $t_j = \sum_{\ell=1}^j x_\ell$. We must have $t_j\ne 0$ for all $j=1,\dots,n$. However, we must also have that $t_i\ne t_j$ for $i <  j$, because $$
t_j - t_i = \sum_{\ell=i+1}^j x_\ell \ne 0
$$
by assumption. This is a contradiction, since $t_j$ are all in a group with only $n$ elements, it cannot take on $n$ distinct values.
On the other hand, we have $F_{n-1}(n) \ge P(X_i=1 \forall i\le n-1) = \frac1{n^{n-1}} > 0$.
Computing $F_k(n)$ for small $k$:
For small $k$, one can compute formulas for $F_{k}(n)$. $F_{1}(n) = 1-\frac1n$ because this is simply the probability that $X_1\ne 0$. $F_{2}(n)$ is similarly easy, if we consider it as a counting problem: There are always $(n-1)$ non-zero choices for $X_1$, and then $n-2$ choices for $X_2$ such that both $X_2\not\equiv 0$ and $X_1+X_2\not\equiv 0$; therefore $F_2(n) = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{n^2}$.
For $F_3(n)$ it begins to become clear why this problem is tricky: As in the $k=2$ case, consider it as a counting problem. (This is rather tricky so I'm not confident that I have it right.) How many $\vec z\in(\mathbb Z / n\mathbb{Z})^3$ have no combination of components equal to $0$? There are $n-1$ choices for $X_1$, then given $X_1$ we have $n-2$ choices for $X_2$ such that $X_2\ne0$ and $X_1+X_2\ne 0$. There are four conditions for $X_3$, namely $X_3\ne 0$ and $X_1+X_3\ne 0$ and $X_2+X_3\ne 0$ and $X_1+X_2+X_3\ne 0$, but since there is a possibility that $X_1=X_2$, they might not all be distinct. If $X_1=X_2$, then we have $n-3$ possibilities for $X_3$, and if $X_1\ne X_2$, then we have $n-4$.
If $n$ is odd, we have that there are $(n-1)(n-3)$ distinct possibilities for $(X_1,X_2)$ with $X_1\ne X_2$, and $n-1$ possibilities for $X_1=X_2$. Thus, for odd $n$, $$
F_3(n) = \frac{(n-1)(n-3)(n-4)+(n-1)(n-3)}{n^3} = \frac{(n-1)(n-3)^2}{n^3}
$$
On the other hand, if $n$ is even, there are $n-2$ possible values for $X_1=X_2$ such that $X_1\ne 0,X_2\ne0,X_1+X_2\ne 0$. When $n$ is even and $X_1\ne \frac n 2$, there are $n-3$ possibilities for an $X_2$ such that $X_2\ne 0$ and $X_1+X_2\ne 0$ and $X_1\ne X_3$, but there are $n-2$ when possibilities if $X_1=\frac n2$. Thus, we have even $n$ $$
F_3(n) = \frac{(n-2)(n-3)+(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)+(n-2)(n-4)}{n^3} = \frac{(n-2)(n^2-5n+5)}{n^3}
$$
and therefore in general (assuming $n\ge 3$): $$
F_3(n) = \begin{cases}
\frac{(n-1)(n-3)^2}{n^3} & n\text{ odd}\\
\frac{(n-2)(n^2-5n+5)}{n^3} & n\text{ even}
\end{cases}
$$
Already, this is looking quite complex! One can verify this solution for small $n$. For $n=4$, the only possibilities are clearly $1,1,1$ and $3,3,3$, hence $F_3(4) = \frac2{4^3} = \frac{(4-2)(4^2-5\cdot 4 + 5)}{4^3}$ as predicted. For $n=5$, the possibilities for rolls with no subset adding up to a multiple of $5$ are $i,i,i$ for $i=1\dots4$ and the permutations of $(1,1,2),(2,2,4),(3,3,1),(4,4,3)$, which is $4+3\cdot 4= 16 = (5-1)(5-3)^2$ as predicted. For $n=6$ the formula again predicts the correct answer, $44$, corresponding to the possible permutations of $$
(1,1,1),(5,5,5),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(2,2,1),(2,2,3),(2,2,5),(4,4,1),(4,4,3),(4,4,5),(5,5,3),(1,3,4),(2,3,5)
$$
Interestingly, $(n-2)(n^2-5n+5)=(n-1)(n-3)^3-1$, so letting $\chi_2(n)=\begin{cases}1&n\text{ even}\\0&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$, we have $$
F_3(n) = \frac{(n-1)(n-3)^2-\chi_2(n)}{n^3}
$$
I attempted to find a formula for $F_4(n)$ along the same lines. The proliferation of different cases to check was quite excessive and I decided that it is probably not the right approach. It seems that $n^4 F_4(n)$ is a distinct 4th degree polynomial depending on which factors $n$ shares with 12, i.e. for six distinct 4th degree polynomials we seem to have $$
n^4 F_4(n) = \begin{cases}
p_1(n) & n \equiv 0 &\mod 12\\
p_2(n) & n \equiv 3,9& \mod 12\\
p_3(n) & n \equiv 6 &\mod 12\\
p_4(n) & n \equiv 2,10 &\mod 12\\
p_5(n) & n \equiv 4,8 &\mod 12\\
p_6(n) & n \equiv 1,5,7,11& \mod 12 
\end{cases}
$$
However, I got bogged down and did not complete computing $p_i(n)$.
Questions about $F_k(n)$
My main question is whether a formula can be found for $F_k(n)$ that is better than the brute force combinatorics approach I used above. It seems clear that the computation of $F_k(n)$ will be easiest when $n$ is a prime number. I wonder if there is a simple formula for $F_k(p)$ for prime $p$, and how much more complicated it is to compute $F_k(n)$ for composite $n$ in general?
It is also, of interest what are the asymptotics of $F_k(n)$ in $n$ and $k$? Since $F_k(n)$ goes to $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity for fixed $k$, but $F_k(n)$ goes to $0$ in finitely many steps as $k$ increases, there would probably a range of relative size of $k$ and $n$ where $F_k(n)$ is asymptotically interesting.

If you have about $2^k$ chances of hitting a multiple of $n$, would the transition region be where $k\approx\log_2 n$?

That seems plausible for sure.

I guess for each natural $i$ and $n$ with $2^i\le n$ for each feasible choices of $X_1,\dots, X_i$ there are at least $n-2^i$ feasible choice of $X_{i+1}$. This should imply that if $2^{k-1}\le n$ then
$$F_k(n)\ge \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} 1-\frac {2^i}n.$$
Moreover, I guess that this bound is asymptotically tight when $k$ is fixed and $n$ tends to the infinity,
because in this case the sums $\sum_{j\in S} X_j$, $S\subset {1,\dots,k}$ usually are distinct.


This data comes from a million random trials for each value of $n=2$ to $100$, and every value of $k=2$ to $10$.  I added exact probabilities of $1/n$ for $k=1$.
The left graph shows the probability of no multiple of $n$, for each value of $k$ from $1$ to $10$, higher $k$ are lower down.
The middle graph shows the probability of at least one multiple of $n$, lower $k$ are lower probabilities.
The right-hand graph shows the same as the left-hand graph, except the x-axis is scaled to $n/2^k$.  Lines of higher $k$ tend to be further left.  They cross over near $n/2^k=0.8, P=0.25$

Assuming that the $n$-faced die is numbered $1,2,...n$ and they are uniformly distributed as $\frac1n,\frac1n,...\frac1n$, let's define coefficients of expansion of $\frac{(1+x+x^2+...x^{n-1})^{k-j}}{n^{k-j}}$, where $j=0,1,...k-1$ as $C[n,k,j]$  (note below at the end of answer), which will be an array. This will correspond to the discrete PDF of $(k-j)$ dice, since the PDF of sum of i.i.d RV is a convolution of their PDFs.
The probability of finding a multiple of $n$ in any of the combinations of $k-j$ dice is then
$$P_{j} = \frac{\binom{k}{k-j}}{(2^k-1)} \sum\limits_{m}C[n,k,j][(k-m)n]$$, where $m = 0,1,..$ while satisfying $m \le \frac{k(n-1)}{n}$.
Therefore the probability of finding a multiple of $n$ in any combination of $k$ dice is $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1} P_{j}$
note: For an example, C[5,k,j] is given by A035343

Edit: Including a full walk-through for $k=5,n=3$ as discussed in the comments.
For $\mathbf{j=4}$ (i.e. sum of 1 dice, no convolution),
Expanding our $f(x) = \frac{(1+x+x^2+...x^{n-1})^{k-j}}{n^{k-j}}$ with $k=5,n=3,j=4$,
$$f(x) = \frac{1+x+x^2}{3}$$
The coefficients are $\frac13,\frac13,\frac13$, which is simply the uniform distribution of 3-faced die for sums $1,2,3$. The PDF can be written as $C[3,5,4][1:3] = (1,\frac13),(2,\frac13),(\color\red{3},\frac13)$ (multiple of $3$ marked in red.
For $\mathbf{j=3}$ (i.e. sum of 2 dice, convolution 1 time),
Expanding our $f(x) = \frac{(1+x+x^2+...x^{n-1})^{k-j}}{n^{k-j}}$ with $k=5,n=3,j=3$,
$$f(x) = \frac{(1+x+x^2)^2}{3^2} = \frac{1+2x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4}{9}$$
This corresponds to PDF of sum of $2$ dice $C[3,5,3][2:6] = (2,\frac19),(\color\red{3},\frac29),(4,\frac39),(5,\frac29),(\color\red{6},\frac19)$
For $\mathbf{j=2}$ (i.e. sum of 3 dice, convolution $2$ times),
Expanding our $f(x) = \frac{(1+x+x^2+...x^{n-1})^{k-j}}{n^{k-j}}$ with $k=5,n=3,j=2$,
$$f(x) = \frac{(1+x+x^2)^3}{3^3} = \frac{1+3x+6x^2+7x^3+6x^4+3x^5+x^6}{27}$$
This corresponds to PDF of sum of $3$ dice $C[3,5,2][3:9] = (\color\red{3},\frac{1}{27}),(4,\frac{3}{27}),(5,\frac{6}{27}),(\color\red{6},\frac{7}{27}),(7,\frac{6}{27}),(8,\frac{3}{27}),(\color\red{9},\frac{1}{27})$
For $\mathbf{j=1}$ (i.e. sum of 4 dice, convolution $3$ times),
Expanding our $f(x) = \frac{(1+x+x^2+...x^{n-1})^{k-j}}{n^{k-j}}$ with $k=5,n=3,j=1$,
$$f(x) = \frac{(1+x+x^2)^4}{3^4} = \frac{1+4x+10x^2+16x^3+19x^4+16x^5+10x^6+4x^7+x^8}{81}$$
This corresponds to PDF of sum of $3$ dice $C[3,5,1][4:12] = (4,\frac{1}{81}),(5,\frac{4}{81}),(\color\red{6},\frac{10}{81}),(7,\frac{16}{81}),(8,\frac{19}{81}),(\color\red{9},\frac{16}{81}),(10,\frac{10}{81}),(11,\frac{4}{81}),(\color\red{12},\frac{1}{81})$
For $\mathbf{j=0}$ (i.e. sum of 5 dice, convolution $4$ times),
Expanding our $f(x) = \frac{(1+x+x^2+...x^{n-1})^{k-j}}{n^{k-j}}$ with $k=5,n=3,j=0$,
$$f(x) = \frac{(1+x+x^2)^5}{3^5} = \frac{1+5x+15x^2+30x^3+45x^4+51x^5+45x^6+30x^7+15x^8+5x^9+x^{10}}{243}$$
This corresponds to PDF of sum of $4$ dice $C[3,5,0][5:15] = (5,\frac{1}{243}),(\color\red{6},\frac{5}{243}),(7,\frac{15}{243}),(8,\frac{30}{243}),(\color\red{9},\frac{45}{243}),(10,\frac{51}{243}),(11,\frac{45}{243}),(\color\red{12},\frac{30}{243}),(13,\frac{15}{243}),(14,\frac{5}{243}),(\color\red{15},\frac{1}{243})$
The fraction of ways of selecting $1$ die is $\frac{\binom{5}{1}}{2^5-1} = \frac{5}{31}$. Using the red colored numbers for $1$ die (i.e. $j=4$),
$$P_{4} = \frac{5}{31} (\frac13) = \frac{5}{93}$$
The fraction of ways of selecting $2$ dice is $\frac{\binom{5}{2}}{2^5-1} = \frac{10}{31}$. Using the red colored numbers for $2$ die (i.e. $j=3$),
$$P_{3} = \frac{10}{31} (\frac29+\frac19) = \frac{10}{93}$$
The fraction of ways of selecting $3$ dice is $\frac{\binom{5}{3}}{2^5-1} = \frac{10}{31}$. Using the red colored numbers for $3$ die (i.e. $j=2$),
$$P_{2} = \frac{10}{31} (\frac{1}{27}+\frac{7}{27}+\frac{1}{27}) = \frac{10}{93}$$
The fraction of ways of selecting $4$ dice is $\frac{\binom{5}{4}}{2^5-1} = \frac{5}{31}$. Using the red colored numbers for $4$ die (i.e. $j=1$),
$$P_{1} = \frac{5}{31} (\frac{10}{81}+\frac{16}{81}+\frac{1}{81}) = \frac{5}{93}$$
The fraction of ways of selecting $5$ dice is $\frac{\binom{5}{5}}{2^5-1} = \frac{1}{31}$. Using the red colored numbers for $5$ die (i.e. $j=0$),
$$P_{0} = \frac{1}{31} (\frac{5}{243}+\frac{45}{243}+\frac{30}{243}+\frac{1}{243}) = \frac{1}{93}$$
$$P_{0}+P_{1}+P_{2}+P_{3}+P_{4} = \frac{31}{93} = \frac13$$.

I am sorry but this is rather hard to follow. Could you include an example of the computation for specific $n$ and $k$ or else give more detail?

OK, I will walk through the steps for $k=5, n=3$. Initially each of the $5$ dice has a distribution of $\frac13,\frac13,\frac13$. When you sum any two of them, you get a distribution as $\frac19,\frac29,\frac39,\frac29,\frac19$. if you sum $3$ of them, you get distribution as $\frac{1}{27},\frac{3}{27},\frac{6}{27},\frac{7}{27},\frac{6}{27},\frac{3}{27},\frac{1}{27}$. And so on (by convolving). When you take only $1$ die, the sums are between $1$ and $3$, where the multiple is only $3$. When you sum $2$ dice, the sums are between $2$ and $6$. But the multiples are at $3$ and $6$....

...contd.
When you sum $3$ dice, the sums are between $3$ and $9$. The multiples are at $3,6,9$. The distribution I showed in each of these cases is the coefficien array. The multiple picking is by starting at the end and going backward, until the condition for $m$ is satisified. Now we need to see the chances of picking $1$ of $5$, $2$ of $5$, ... which is the binomial term you see. Finally I sum all the probabilities. The main part is to find a closed form for the r-fold convolution of a discrete uniform distribution. I found that in the OEIS , which I just extrapolated for the general case

Sorry, forgot to divide by the total number of combinations in the binomial term. Added. Denominator is $\sum\limits_{p=1}^{k} \binom{k}{p} = 2^k - 1$

I don't understand your notation in the definition of $P_j$. And I'm not totally clear on what $P_j$ is supposed to represent anyway. Is it the probably that some combination of exactly $(k-j)$ of the dice sum to a multiple of $n$? If so, it is not hard to see that this should be exactly $1/n$ always. But you can't just sum them up because, e.g., a sum of two dice being divisible by $n$ is not mutually exclusive with a sum of three being divisible by $n$.

So in your example, what does $F_5(3)$ work out to be? I don't know what your formula has me doing with the convolution coefficients. As I showed in the OP this should work out to $0$ because $k\ge n$.

(my mistake, it's only $1/n$ if you are looking at any particular subset of the dice)

First of all, there was a missing summation in my formula for $P_{j}$ whcih I added now (sorry for repeated edits). I will try to post a more detailed walk-through tonight (sevral hours later).

Sorry I just noticed that you are asking for "no combination of k dice" resulting in multiple of $n$. My answer is for "any combination of k dice" resulting in multiple of $n$". I don't want to change my answer now after all this discussion. I believe we can derive one from the other. But if you insist, I can delete the answer or leave it open for any downvotes

I do not understand your general idea still. Is $P_j$ supposed to be the probability that at least one subset of size $k-j$ sums to a multiple of $n$? If so then the formula is incorrect, because (for $n=3,k=5$) we should have $P_4=1-P($no dice comes up 3$)=1-(2/3)^5=211/243$.

I'll need to look at it more carefully in the morning. Clearly you put in a lot of effort and I appreciate that, but I don't see exactly what you are solving for through all of it.

$P_{2}$ correspnds to the probability of getting a sum that is a multiple of $3$, when randomly selected $3$ of $5$ dice are used for the sum. $P_{1}$ correspnds to the probability of getting a sum that is a multiple of $3$, when randomly selected $4$ of $5$ dice are used for the sum. Getting a mutiple of $3$ somehow by combining $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$ or $5$ dice is what my formula is for.

Oh I see. So then the end result is answering the question of, "if I select a random subset of k dice, what is the probability the sum is a multiple of n?" Yes that is something different than the problem I was asking about. I do not think it is related in a simple way, but also an interesting question
